# Using the Docker API how do I determine how long a container took to reach healthy state?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to understand from the [Container inspect API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.43/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerInspect) how long it took for a container to reach the first healthy state.  So I can print out a metric of "start time" and "how long has it been running for"

The State.Health.Log only tracks the most recent ones but not the initial one.

State.Health.StartedAt is a few millis after the CreatedAt so that wasn't it.